# Python MySQLdb cursor.execute() insert with varying number of values

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Similar questions have been asked, but all of them - for example [This One](http://def%20insert_values(table,%20columns,%20values,%20database):%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22%20%20%20%20%20columns%20-%20a%20string%20representing%20tuple%20with%20corresponding%20columns%20%20%20%20%20values%20-%20a%20tuple%20containing%20values%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22%20%20%20%20%20query=database.cursor()%20%20%20%20%20#%20print%20'%5CnValues%20%7B%7D%20inserted%20into%20%7B%7D%5Cn'.format(str(values),table)%20%20%20%20%20query.execute(%22INSERT%20INTO%20%60%7B%7D%60%20%7B%7D%20VALUES%7B%7D%22.format(table,columns,str(values)))) deals only with specified number of values.

for example, I tried to do this the following way:

```
def insert_values(table, columns, values, database):
    """
    columns - a string representing tuple with corresponding columns
    values - a tuple containing values
    """
    query=database.cursor()
    query.execute("INSERT INTO `{}` {} VALUES{}".format(table,columns,str(values)))
```

But that's no good - although the insert initially seemed fine (accepted and commited to database), soon the data types errors began, which came from converting all data types to string. For example:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = %s AND baz = %s", (param1, param2))
```

My initial way also involved pre-converting datetime objects, which is probably not what the creators of MySQLdb had in mind.

The way I saw in other examples for MySQLdb involves string interpolation, but that means defined number of variables as '%s', and it gives no flexibility to the code.

How could I define a method, which could take an arbitrary, previously undefined number of values that would be compatibile with MySQLdb? Is it possible? Or am I missing something about string interpolation?

[edit] example usage of a method I had in mind:

two databases: source_db, destination_db

```
row = source_db.cursor.execute('SELECT x from Y where z='1')
```

(returns tuple)

```
insert_values('table_name','(column_name_1,column_name_2)',row, destination_db)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use string interpolation to produce placeholders for the content, then allow the DB-API to populate them. For example:

```
placeholders = ','.join('%s' for col in columns)
query_string = "INSERT INTO `{}` {} VALUES ({})".format(table, columns, placeholders)
query.execute(query_string, values)
```

Comment: This looks mighty fine, and thank you for this, but this returns error in my case. **query.execute(query_string, values)**  returns TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple, while **query.execute(query_string% values)** when a field is returned by MySQLdb as dict, gives a MySQL syntax error. For example, select returned a tuple:    ('default', 'Default', 1, 26L, '{"description": "content available"}')  and this gives an error  _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; (...) use near \'description":

Comment: I'm sorry if that's unclear, but replies are very limited when it comes to formatting ;/

Comment: I think you just need parens around the values - edited.

Comment: values_tmp=[str(value).replace('"',"'") if type(value)==str else value for value in values]   ->  values=tuple(values_tmp)   - this worked for replacing the double quotes with single quotes. Now the whole query works... Is this kind of struggling normal with MySQLdb lib?

Comment: No, and there is no reason to do that. The code I showed above works fine - the library escapes the quotes for you.

Comment: My bad. The source database had a column named 'key', which is a reserved word. Since I provide column names as a string, adding a ` before 'key' and after solved it. Probably will have to do it in a few other places.

Thank you for your patience - the databases are huge and very complex, and this is my first time working with  both complex MySQL and MySQLdb, so problems raise here and there.

Thank you so much.