# Insert an array in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, insert, psycopg2

I use python to connect to my postgresql database.
I parse a XML fill to populate my base, so I have an array[] of values for one line to insert. I have something like this:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO ACTIVITYDESC VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3],value[4]))
```

There is a way to make this more simple like: ?

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO ACTIVITYDESC VALUES (%s)""",(value))
```

Thank for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python MySQLdb cursor.execute() insert with varying number of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520737/python-mysqldb-cursor-execute-insert-with-varying-number-of-values)

Comment: @ozgur Not a duplicate of that question. Many differences including the DB

Comment: I have try this but it's doesn't work in my case, but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the list into a tuple:

```
t = tuple(value)
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO ACTIVITYDESC VALUES %s""",(t,))
```